# How to calculate the distance moved during PointerMoved event of Canvas in UWP?

Tags: uwp-xaml

```
 Canvas c=new Canvas();
 c.Width=1200;
 c.Height=700;
 c.PointerMoved+=Moved;
 private void Moved(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        PointerPoint CurrentPosition = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as Canvas);
        Point PointerPosition = CurrentPosition.Position;

 }
```

I don't Know how to calculate the distance moved during this event.The PointerPosition gives the current (x and y).I need to calculate the distance moved during this event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PointerMoved` event is a continuously triggered event. If you want to calculate the distance the pointer moves, you need to have a "start point".

```cs
Point StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);

...
c.PointerEntered += Entered;

private void Entered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PointerPoint CurrentPosition = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as Canvas);
    StartPoint = CurrentPosition.Position;
}

private void Moved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PointerPoint CurrentPosition = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as Canvas);
    Point PointerPosition = CurrentPosition.Position;
    double xDistance = Math.Abs(PointerPosition.X - StartPoint.X);
    double yDistance = Math.Abs(PointerPosition.Y - StartPoint.Y);
    double Distance = Math.Sqrt(xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance);
}
```

---

**Update**

If we need to calculate the change in the pointer position between two `PointerMoved` events, we need to introduce a variable to record the last pointer position.

```cs
Point PreviousPoint;
private void Moved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PointerPoint CurrentPosition = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as Canvas);
    Point PointerPosition = CurrentPosition.Position;
    if (PreviousPoint != null)
    {
        double xDistance = Math.Abs(PointerPosition.X - PreviousPoint.X);
        double yDistance = Math.Abs(PointerPosition.Y - PreviousPoint.Y);
        double Distance = Math.Sqrt(xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance);
        // TODO use Distance
    }
    PreviousPoint = PointerPosition;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: PointerEntered will be triggered only once when mouse point enetered into Canvas.But mouseMoved event will be triggered continuously when moving mouse point inside canvas.Then how it will be correct?It Produces wrong results?For each pointermoved event ,i want to calculate the distance moved?

Comment: Hello, the method shows the straight-line distance relative to the start point during the mouse movement. The start point is updated when the `PointerEnterted` event is triggered, and the relative distance is updated each time the mouse moves. What do you mean by the moving distance? Is the distance moved by the mouse during the triggering of two `PointerMoved` events?

Comment: yeah you are right....distance moved by the mouse during the triggering of two PointerMoved events

Comment: Hello, sorry for the misunderstanding, I have updated the answer, please kindly check it.

Comment: yeah.Its working fine.but what i have tried is e.GetIntermediatePoints(sender as Canvas).It returns list of intermediate points during PointerMovedEvent.But what's the problem is ,it returns only one Point same as current point.I have an idea to calculate the distance from intermediate points.Can u please check this  also why it returns only one point?

Comment: Hello, `Pointer` related events are low-level events, and the results returned by the `GetIntermediatePoints` method will vary depending on the input device. For mouse device, it is recommended to use variables to record position changes.